# What's the best usage for mockOIdcLogin() for WebTestClient?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux

I'm currently working on a senior project and we decided to use Spring Webflux for our backend and Google as our OAuth2.0 provider. I am currently trying to run some integration tests using Spock and Groovy on some endpoints that are secured behind OAuth2.0 authentication. The endpoint does not use the Authentication principal for anything, is just not supposed to be accessed by someone who isn't authenticated. However, reading the Spring documentation and I came across the method for a webTestClient to use a mock open id connect login in which I might not need to do mock the entire OAuth2 process, however, this is giving me a HTTP 302 status

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = "spring.main.web-application-type=reactive")
class UserControllerITSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    ReactiveWebApplicationContext context

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient client

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(wireMockConfig()
            .port(8077))

    def setup() {
        client = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
                .configureClient()
                .build()
        
    }

    def "getAllUsers is successful"() {
        given: "a request"
        def request = client.mutateWith(mockOidcLogin()).get().uri("/api/v2/users/getAllUsers")

        stubFor(post("/graphql/")
                .withHeader("Authorization", equalTo("F9v4MUqdQuWAh3Wqxe11mteqPfPedUqp78VaQNJt8DSt"))
                .withHeader("content-type", equalTo("application/json"))
                .withHeader("accept", equalTo("application/json"))
                .withRequestBody(equalTo("""{
                          "query": "query { list_UserItems { _UserItems { _id email displayName appointments } } }",
                          "variables": null,
                          "operationName": null
                        }"""))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBodyFile("vendiaResponses/getAllUsersResponse.json")))

        stubFor(get("/oauth2/authorization/wiremock")
                .willReturn(status(200)))

        when: "the request is sent"
        def response = request.exchange()

        then: "an OK status is returned"
        response.expectStatus()
                .isOk()

    }
}
```

Is my understanding of the `mutateWith(mockOidcLogin())` method incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using `webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK`

Are you sure about the `Authentication` implementation you have at runtime? (you can have `Authentication auth` [auto-magically injected as @Controller method parameter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/b6142cd5cfb570f3d47589754307c36de3f31d19/samples/webflux-jwt-default/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webflux_jwtauthenticationtoken/GreetingController.java#L36) and inspect it with your favorite debugger or log its class)

Isn't there anything of help in those samples: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples (look at those containing `webflux` in their name and focus on test classes ending with `ItegrationTest` in their name like [this one](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/webflux-jwt-default/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webflux_jwtauthenticationtoken/SampleApiIntegrationTests.java))

If their isn't a test annotation for your spring Authentication type in the repo yet, open an issue. I might consider implement it.

Comment: The reason why I went with the `SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED` is because I wanted to see it run in a non-mocked environment. I also checked the snippets in the repo, however, I'm not sure what exactly those integration tests are doing.

Comment: Integration tests (`@SpringBootTest`) assert that components (controllers, services and repositories) are working fine when wired together (with mocked user identities), as opposed to unit tests (other test classes decorated with `@WebfluxTest` or `@WebMvcTest` for controllers or @Service and @Repository tests) which finely test that components work in isolation (with mocked identities too, but also mocked dependencies)

Comment: P.S. testing with a non mocked environment might mean having an authorization-server at hand, issuing valid access tokens. Your tests will be heavy (need docker images or something for authorization-server) and slow (docker image lifting and additional network calls to issue access-tokens). I personnaly prefer to keep that for "smoke" tests.

Comment: I may not have all my definitions down, but if I were to mock the Oauth2 calls using wireMock, would that be considered a mocked environment or non-mocked environment? I initially wanted to do that and had written some stubs for replacing what Google’s oauth2.0 service does, how do you feel about that?

Comment: If you use wiremock to provide authorization-codes or access-tokens, validation in Spring JWT decoder will fail (you will never have access to Google private key to sign JWTs content)

Comment: Quick update: I wasn't injecting a user with @WithMockUser... that was it, apologies.

Comment: Don not use `@WithMockUser` with OAuth2 resource-server. Just click the links to the samples in my answer for `@WithMockJwtAuth` or `mockJwt()` WebTestClient mutator (what you're trying to do with `mockOidcLogin()` mutator is to for client authentication)

Comment: My application is neither a resource or authorization server.

Comment: @WithMockUser builds a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. If your app is OAuth2, even a client, it uses for sure an other Authentication implementation. You question is missing dependencies (Maven or Gradle), security conf and controller code for answer to be precise